# Visible property not showing the controls

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, visibility

I have created an aspx page in which I want some controls to be enabled on basis of user selection.

If user selects `All` two radio buttons should be enabled, hide otherwise.

My declarative part is:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCommunityMembers" runat="server" Text="Community Members" />
    </td>
    <td>

        <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCommunityMembers" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbCommunityMembersAll" runat="server" Text="All" GroupName="grpCommMembers" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdbCommunityMembersAll_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers" runat="server" Text="Selected Users" GroupName="grpCommMembers" OnCheckedChanged="rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />        
                <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ID="ppCommunityMembers" runat="server" AllowMultipleEntities="true" AllowEmpty="false" Visible="false" />
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCommunityCatagory" runat="server" Text="Community Catagory" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCommunityCatagory" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">---- Select One ----</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCommunityCatagory" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="Please Select Community Catagory"
             ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddlCommunityCatagory" Display="Dynamic" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCommunityAccess" runat="server" Text="Required Approval?" Visible="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbRequiredApprovalYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="grpCommMembers" Checked="true" Visible="false" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbRequiredApprovalNo" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="grpCommMembers" Visible="false"/>        
    </td>        

</tr>
```

My code behind:

```
protected void rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers.Checked)
        {
            enableControls();


        }
        else
        {
            disableControls();

        }
    }

    protected void rdbCommunityMembersAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbCommunityMembersAll.Checked)
        {
            disableControls();

        }
        else
        {
            enableControls();
        }
    }

    protected void enableControls()
    {
        ppCommunityMembers.Visible = true;
        lblCommunityAccess.Visible = true;
        rdbRequiredApprovalNo.Visible = true;
        rdbRequiredApprovalYes.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void disableControls()
    {
        ppCommunityMembers.Visible = false;
        lblCommunityAccess.Visible = false;
        rdbRequiredApprovalNo.Visible = false;
        rdbRequiredApprovalYes.Visible = false;
    }
```

If Community members are selected to all then "Required Approval?" part should get hidden.

But problem is when I select selected users then I am getting only people picker control visible, the required approval contorls are not getting displayed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your Radio Buttons rdbCommunityMembersAll and rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers are inside update panel, thus they are doing partial postback. To make the control visible outside the UpdatePanel you can do **any one** of the following:

1. Move rdbCommunityMembersAll  and rdbCommunityMembersSelectedUsers 
   outside the UpdatePanel
2. Move the controls you need to make visible
   (lblCommunityAccess, rdbRequiredApprovalNo, rdbRequiredApprovalYes)
       inside UpdatePanel

   **Or**
3. Instead of setting Visible="false", set style="display:none" and
   trigger the visibility through javascript/jquery